# Adding opacity to the dots in a Mapbox cluster

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In an attempt to improve the user experience for Mapbox clusters on dark maps, is there a way to add different opacities to the dots?

[image]

```
map.addLayer({
  id: 'clusters',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'counties',
  filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
  paint: {
    'circle-color': [
      'step',
      ['get', 'point_count'],
      '#0000FF',  # Less transparency
      10,
      '#0000FF',  # Little transparency
      50,
      '#0000FF'   # No transparency
    ],
    'circle-radius': [
      'step',
      ['get', 'point_count'],
      10,
      100,
      50,
      1000,
      100
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [circle-opacity](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-circle-circle-opacity):

```
'circle-color': '#0000FF',
'circle-opacity': [
    'step',
    ['get', 'point_count'],
    0.25,
    10,
    0.5,
    50,
    0.75
],
```

or rgba

```
'circle-color': [
    'step',
    ['get', 'point_count'],
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25)',
    10,
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
    50,
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75)',
],
```